# Dynamically Updating a PYQT Menu Item

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.8

I've constructed a Qmenu item that contains a list of recently opened files using the following construction. I'd like to update the menubar in real time, such that I don't have to wait until the next time the app is run for the menubar to be updated.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Application, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.settings = {}
        self.settings['recent files'] = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.menu_bar()

    def menu_bar(self):
        file_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu('&File', self)
        self.recent = file_menu.addMenu('&Open Recent')

        for filename in self.settings['recent files']:
            self.recent.addAction(f'{filename}', lambda source=filename: self.dialog_open_file(file_name=source))

        self.menuBar().addMenu(file_menu)

    def dialog_open_file(self):
        
        self.settings['recent files'] = ['filename 4', 'filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']

        self.update_recent_files()

        # do lots more stuff

    def update_recent_files(self):

        # Update list of recent files in Open Recent menubar  <---- 

qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
application_window = Application()
application_window.setWindowTitle(f"My App")
application_window.show()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

My actual code works well (with the exception of updating the menu in real time). It writes the list of recent files to a persistent json on disk (the sample code does not include that bit). When a user opens a new file, the filename is successfully inserted into the list of recent files. The next time the app is run, the Recent Files menu shows the updated list.

However, I'd like the menu list of recent files to be dynamic. How would I best go about calling for the Recent Files menu to be rebuilt in real time?

***EDIT*** -- I've attempted to clarify the question to focus on the dynamic update of the menu item and not on the persistent maintenance of
the list of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save information persistently then you must save that information on the hard drive (in a file), and there are many alternatives in python and also in Qt such as QSettings. The logic is to load the information when the window is created, and save it when necessary (for example when the window is closed).

```py
import sys
from functools import cached_property
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Application, self).__init__(parent)

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.create_menu_file()

        self.load_settings()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Load new files")
        button.clicked.connect(self.another_task)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def create_menu_file(self):
        file_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu("&File", self)
        self.recentfiles_menu = file_menu.addMenu("&Open Recent")
        self.recentfiles_menu.triggered.connect(self.handle_triggered_recentfile)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(file_menu)

    @cached_property
    def settings(self):
        return QtCore.QSettings()

    def load_settings(self):
        filenames = self.settings.value("recent_files", [])
        for filename in filenames:
            self.add_recent_filename(filename)

    def save_settings(self):
        recentfiles = []
        for action in self.recentfiles_menu.actions()[::-1]:
            recentfiles.append(action.text())
        self.settings.setValue("recent_files", recentfiles)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAction)
    def handle_triggered_recentfile(self, action):
        self.process_filename(action.text())

    def add_recent_filename(self, filename):
        action = QtWidgets.QAction(filename, self)
        actions = self.recentfiles_menu.actions()
        before_action = actions[0] if actions else None
        self.recentfiles_menu.insertAction(before_action, action)

    def process_filename(self, filename):
        print(filename)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super(Application, self).closeEvent(event)
        self.save_settings()

    def another_task(self):
        # DEMO
        # load new filenames
        counter = len(self.recentfiles_menu.actions())
        filenames = [f"foo {counter}"]
        for filename in filenames:
            self.add_recent_filename(filename)


qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
application_window = Application()
application_window.setWindowTitle(f"My App")
application_window.show()

sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question.  It looks like you're recommending the use of QSettings over my current approach that saves application settings to a json file.  In other words, I'm already able to save the list of recently opened files in my json and recall them when the menubar list is initially populated.  Is it necessary to use QSettings to update the menubar dynamically (i.e., the only way)?  The reason I ask is that your recommendation would require refactoring other aspects of my application (several other aspects are managed centrally with the json approach).

Comment: @DaveL17 1) You never mentioned that you use json, 2) My solution is just a recommendation, the same logic also applies if you use json, yaml, etc. 3) My logic is for any type of class that allows you to save information permanently, 4) I am not pointing out one better than another since that will depend on your application but in your case, being a simple application, none would be of interest.

Comment: @DaveL17 5) Please do not assume that we are magicians who guess what your project has, we only focus on the code you provide, nothing more. The last thing I point out because it is really annoying that after giving you an answer you signal other conditions.

Comment: @DaveL17 Finally, if you want to use json you just have to modify the load_settings and save_settings methods

Comment: Apologies. I could've been more clear with my question. The statement below the code block is meant to convey my current use of json -- "This works well. When a user opens a new file, the filename is inserted into the list of recent files (and also written out to a settings json file). The next time the app is run, the Recent Files menu shows the updated list."  I clearly should've worded this better. Sorry to have caused frustration for you. I really don't want to appear ungrateful, and very much appreciate you taking the time.

Answer (score 3):

When the contents of a menu are dynamic, I usually prefer to use the [`aboutToShow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#aboutToShow) signal of QMenu, which is triggered right before it's going to be opened, and connect to a function that clears it and updates its contents.

I also use [`QAction.setData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#setData) to store the file name, which allows to show a customized text (for example, if the path is too long, we can elide it, or show the file name only instead of the full path).

```
class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Application, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        self.recent_menu = file_menu.addMenu('&Open recent')

        self.recent_menu.aboutToShow.connect(self.update_recent_menu)
        self.recent_menu.triggered.connect(self.open_file_from_recent)
        self.settings = {}

    def update_recent_menu(self):
        self.recent_menu.clear()
        for row, filename in enumerate(self.get_recent_files(), 1):
            recent_action = self.recent_menu.addAction('&{}. {}'.format(
                row, filename))
            recent_action.setData(filename)

    def get_recent_files(self):
        recent = self.settings.get('recent files')
        if not recent:
            # just for testing purposes
            recent = self.settings['recent files'] = ['filename 4', 'filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3']
        return recent

    def open_file_from_recent(self, action):
        self.open_file(action.data())

    def open_file(self, filename):
        recent = self.get_recent_files()
        if filename in recent:
            recent.remove(filename)
        recent.insert(0, filename)
        
        print(filename)
```

Comment: This is a great tip, thank you.  I was able to apply @eyllanesc 's answer to good effect but do like this approach as well.  Both of your answers remind me that I need to be vigilant about making my methods more Pythonic.  Cheers.

Comment: I just followed this to dynamically update my own menu with the `aboutToShow` method. Thanks so much!